# Javascript How to convert String to HTMLTableRowElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a function witch has an `HTMLTableRowElement` parameter as input and has to return `HTMLTableRowElement` back.

But before I return the variable I have it convert to a string first so that I could replace some words inside it.

Below you see an example of the `HTMLTableRowElement` content

```
var item = '<tr id="contacts_list_:id"><td id="contacts_id_:id" class="id"></td><td id="contacts_name_:id" class="name"></td><td id="contacts_city_:id" class="city"></td></tr>'; /* example */
```

Below you see an example of the function

```
function Converter(item){

/* convert HTMLTableRowElement to string to make changes */
var itemSource = item.innerHTML.replace(/:id/g, item['_values'].id);

/* Howto convert  itemSource  back to HTMLTableRowElement? */
return itemSource;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [three ways to create dom-elements without jquery](http://garystorey.com/2017/02/27/three-ways-to-create-dom-elements-without-jquery) blog.

Comment: Thx, problem solved :)

Comment: @JeroenHeier link updated https://garystorey.com/how-to-create-dom-elements-without-j-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery  [append()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) method to solve this.